# Running functions sequentially without nesting the functions - jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

Ideally I would like to run these functions sequentially. Formatted like so:

```
function functionOne() {
    $('.div').animate({'height', 200}, 1000);
}

function functionTwo () {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
});
```

I know I can nest functionTwo inside of functionOne's 'complete' callback function (below), but I'd rather not as it can get a little messy.

```
function functionOne() {
    $('.div').animate({'height', 200}, 1000, function() {
        functionTwo();
    });
}
```

Any way around this? Cheers

Comment: what is `messy` about nesting functions?

Comment: No but you don't have to next functionTwo inside of the anonymous function. -- $('.div').animate({...},functionTwo);

Comment: I have a script that is quite large and I have functions being re-used by various events and methods. It's getting a little messy

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use:

```
function functionOne(callback) {
    $('.div').animate({'height', 200}, 1000, callback);
}

function functionTwo () {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    functionOne(function2);
});
```

Although in my opinion:

```
$(function(){
    $('.div').animate({'height', 200}, 1000, function(){
        // ...
    });
};
```

is more readable (depending on the size of your function2) and does the exact same thing faster.